# Failed to restart mysql for 19.10 update

Tags: mysql, 19.10

the installation process fails to install updates because mysql couldn't be restarted for GNU libc library upgrade.

So it asks me to run `invoke-rc.d <service> start` on my terminal, which I did and received the following output:

```
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-10-28 08:52:05 -03; 5ms ago
  Process: 8689 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=217/USER)
```

The output for `ystemctl status mysql.service` is:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-10-28 08:52:06 -03; 41min ago
  Process: 8695 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=217/USER)

out 28 08:52:06 tadeusvult systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduli
out 28 08:52:06 tadeusvult systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is 
out 28 08:52:06 tadeusvult systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
out 28 08:52:06 tadeusvult systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
out 28 08:52:06 tadeusvult systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
out 28 08:52:06 tadeusvult systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Command `journalctl -xe` gives me:

```
out 28 09:33:12 tadeusvult gnome-shell[1995]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to update overlay
out 28 09:33:12 tadeusvult systemd[1789]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
-- Subject: Unidade UNIT sendo iniciado
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A unidade UNIT está sendo iniciada.
out 28 09:33:12 tadeusvult dbus-daemon[1822]: [session uid=1000 pid=1822] Successfully activated s
out 28 09:33:12 tadeusvult systemd[1789]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
-- Subject: Unidade UNIT concluiu a inicialização
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A unidade UNIT concluiu a inicialização.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:13 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: Window manager warning: Overwriting exis
out 28 09:33:40 tadeusvult systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit fprintd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
out 28 09:34:21 tadeusvult org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1995]: [9070:9070:1028/093421.764601:ERROR:buff
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I suggest that you try running the two commands suggested in the output you got, `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe` and then edit your question to include the information that gibves as well.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated it with these outputs

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50506242/6708867 -- it suggests that you could run `mysqld --help --verbose` which is supposed to simulate starting your mysql server and giving you some info about what goes wrong in case it fails. Maybe try that and add that result also to your question?